# CSS Gutter overflowing body

Tags: css, gutter

In my homemade CSS grid i have a problem.
If my .row edges touches the body edge, it will generate overflow.
See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/57BGe/3/ **UPDATED FOR EXPLANATION**

```
.row {
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

How could i prevent the overflow? *(overflow: none, won't work since you still can scroll on phone and with some force on desktop)*

*** UPDATE ***
If you look at Bootstrap #http://getbootstrap.com/css/
Try using dev console and change the margin-left of .row to something that would make overflow on body. *(e.g. -150px)*
If i do this, i still cant scroll horisontal.

Comment: Why not remove the CSS on `.row`? There is no overflow then.

Comment: It's a responsive design, and i can't know if it edges up to the body edge.

Comment: And i want them to align the edge, not have white-space by the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
I tried to put overflow: hidden on body and html, but i could still scroll.
So i made a container with overflow: hidden, and wrapped everything inside it.

That made it work just fine. Abit of a dirty workaround, but it had to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the Browsers agent stylesheet which automatically sets margin and padding on the body and html, then you can get rid of the negative margin:

```
body, html {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Give that a try.